# Possible to overload on YouTube API calls?

Tags: json, youtube-api

A project I am working on makes multiple calls to the YouTube gdata API. Usually when I am using the site heavily and going through several pages that use the API, I just stop getting any returns from the API. Those parts of the site load fine, but things usually gathered by the API suddenly cease to load for a while. Is this because the API can't handle successive calls from me like that or because my code is bad?

I know this probably isn't the most constructive answer for Stack Overflow, so please let me know if I need to remove it.

Comment: It can be constructive question if you add some code and your approach.
Btw, there's a limit on maximum no of api calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you hit some kind of request throttling. As said in the FAQ https://developers.google.com/youtube/faq#operation_limits Youtube limits various of options to prevent to much data/requests.